# What is the easiest way to intercept and manipulate the entity in entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-6

In the technological stack I have a SQL database which is used as database first in Entity Framework v6.1.3 to expose it to the rest of the .Net application.

I am attempting to manipulate the entity before returning it to the higher layers of the application so that the data in certain properties is masked/scrambled. Doing the same in the database is not an option.

The architecture of the application pushes me in the direction of trying to implement it at the lowest possible layer.

The lowest layer for me is somewhere in Entity Framework. I have made an attempt with simplistic approach to change getters in the generated classes.

```
private string _columnX;        
public string ColumnX {
get {
        if (x) { return "*";  }
        return _columnX;
    }
set { _columnX = value; }
```

This works for simple queries. However, as soon as a query gets a bit more complicated and I am accessing this entity via navigation properties EF seems to avoid using this code and relies on some internally generated magic.

I have found some info on IDbCommandInterceptor but I am not sure if I can use it for my scenario and how to manipulate returned entities with it.
[Can I access the entity in IDbCommandInterceptor in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20420067/can-i-access-the-entity-in-idbcommandinterceptor-in-entity-framework)

The question is: Is there some kind of intermediate layer between EF and my database or some configuration in EF that would make it possible to manipulate the data in entity for every case that this data is queried?

**UPDATE**
I have used the suggested approach using `ObjectMaterialized`.
The mentioned in the answer/comments problem with projections remain. As it is discussed in the other question if projections are used this approach is not working.

Is there a way to also force a check on projections so that the data in a given column can be manipulated?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework 5 - Looking for Central Point to Execute Custom Code after Entity is Loaded from Database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712645/entity-framework-5-looking-for-central-point-to-execute-custom-code-after-enti) - also applicable to EF6

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look there!

Comment: I have updated the question based on the other answer