# EF CF - List<T> of Primitive Type

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have the following:

```
public class Broadcast {

    public int NumUsersToMessage { get; set; }
    public int NumMessagesQueued { get; set; }
    public string DbUsersMessaged { get; set; }


    public int NumMessagesSent {
        get {
            return UsersMessaged.Count();
        }
    }

    public List<int> UsersMessaged {

        get {
            return DbUsersMessaged == null ? new List<int>() : DbUsersMessaged.Split(',').Select(Int32.Parse).ToList();
        }
        set {
            DbUsersMessaged = value != null ? String.Join(",", value) : null;
        }
    }
}
```

My goal here is to only ever access `DbUsersMessaged` through `UsersMessaged`.  I'm attempting to do `broadcast.UsersMessaged.Add(2)`, however since this is not an assignment, I can't get the property to behave as I like.  Instead, I have to do this:

```
 tempList = broadcast.UsersMessaged();
 tempList.Add(2);
 broadcast.UsersMessaged = tempList;
 db.SaveChanges();
```

Which is obviously unwieldy.  I'm considering making an `AddReassign` extension method but I want to know - what's the standard practice here for supporting Lists of primitive types?  It looks like even with the extension method, my best shot looks like this:

```
 broadcast.UsersMessaged = broadcast.UsersMessaged.AddReassign(2) // yuck!
```

*Before anyone asks - we've intentionally denormalized this for performance reasons.*

Comment: the only way I can see is to override the .Add() method and either call the setter within or behave the same way.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about performance, you can create own list:

```
public class MyList : IList<int>
{
    private List<int> underlyingList;
    private Broadcast entity;

    public MyList(Broadcast entity)
    {
         this.entity = entity;
         this.underlyingList = entity.DbUsersMessaged?.Split(",") ?? new List<int>();
    }

    public void Add(int i)
    {
         this.underlyingList.Add(i);
         this.entity.DbUsersMessaged  = String.Join(",", underylingList);
    }

    // other interface memebers impl
}
```

Then

```
MyList list;
public IList<int> UsersMessaged {
    get {
        return myList ?? (myList = new MyList(this));
    }
}
```

Of course it is only sample.

Comment: *If you don't care about performance, you can create own list* What do yo mean by that? What's the performance problem of creating own lists?

Comment: @IvanStoev perofrmance problem is in `Add` method. Every `Add` call creates new string. I believie that could be buffered or make it "lazy".

Comment: I see. Make sense. But the OP current implantation with get, add, assign is much worse. Your idea is much better, I liked it, just was curious about the performance statement at the beginning. +1

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to have a look at this: [Entity Framework 5 - Looking for Central Point to Execute Custom Code after Entity is Loaded from Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712645/entity-framework-5-looking-for-central-point-to-execute-custom-code-after-enti)

And then convert from string to list, and then use [Saving Changes event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.savingchanges(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert back into the string construction when saving.

Then, for performance, maybe you want to use `byte[]` rather than a string for storing the data in the database.